# Select column name dynamically based on rows from another table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to make below situation. I need a.DATE_TIME field to find right column name in parentheses. Because there are columns for each days and I need calculate day from SHIFT_TABLE. Column names start with 'TPR' plus day like TPR13

```
DECLARE @SQLText NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT  @SQLText += 'SELECT (SELECT '
SELECT  @SQLText += ( 'TPR' +  Convert(varchar,DATEPART(day,a.DATE_TIME) )
        ) +
        ' from SHIFT_TABLE as s Where s.id = a.id ) from MAIN_TABLE as a where a.id=''1'' and a.ay=''12'' and a.yil=''2018''  '

print @SQLText
```

I take error message: The multi-part identifier "a.DATE_TIME" could not be bound.

SHIFT_TABLE occurs id and TPR01,TPR02,...TPR31 columns
MAIN_TABLE occurs id, ay, yil and DATE_TIME columns

I have to calculate day from a.DATE_TIME.

As a result I try to reach like this, SELECT (SELECT TPR13 from SHIFT_TABLE as s Where s.id = a.id ) from MAIN_TABLE as a where a.id='1' and a.ay='12' and a.yil='2018'

How can I solve it? Many Thanks,

Comment: You can probably use UNPIVOT instead of writing such a query. Post the tables' schema, some sample data and what you expect as the output. BTW you *don't* use any other table in the query right now. You a have a single statement that contatenates strings and contains a `Convert(varchar,DATEPART(day,a.DATE_TIME) )` function call. There are no tables involved here, which is why you get that error.

Comment: Or you could use a `CASE WHEN` clause in your SELECT to return different columns based on the day.

Comment: Hello, if it is possible, could you give example or correct above code please? I tried many different methods but I couldnt find easy way.

Comment: I can't because you didn't explain what you want to do. No table schema, no expected results. Do you have only one table? Why does the title say `from another table` then?

Comment: I added details in my question. Could you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @SQLText NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT  @SQLText += 'SELECT (SELECT '
SELECT  @SQLText += ( 'TPR' +  Convert(varchar,DATEPART(day,a.DATE_TIME) )
    ) +
    ' from SHIFT_TABLE as s Where s.id = a.id ) from MAIN_TABLE as a where a.id=''1'' and a.ay=''12'' and a.yil=''2018''  '
FROM [YourTableWhere_DATE_TIME_Exists] AS a
print @SQLText
```